# Whether the number of objects in R environment will affect the efficiency of R?

Tags: r

Every time when I close R, then I will be asked save workspace image or not, I always choose to save option for convenience. Today I found there so many objects exist in my R environment that, when I close R, the prompt  `"Saving workspace to ~/.RData"` will appear on my window about one minute, and next time when I start R, the prompt `"Loading workspace to ~/.RData"` will also appear on my window about one minute.

I wonder whether the number of objects in R environment will affect the efficiency of R? If I clear some objects in R environment, whether the wait time will reduce when I close and start R?

Comment: Close vote explanation. This is a workflow issue. Asking for opinion. I _Always_ say no to the question. Learn to save projects.

Comment: Well, not really solely opinion. If one chooses to have the environment saved/loaded to/from a RData file on shutdown/startup of R, of course it will get slower the bigger the size of the data, but the environment itself won't necessarily be slower since it doesn't look up objects iteratively. But, I agree that this q is at least "off topic" for SO.

Comment: I don't think this is off topic. It's almost in line of profiling code, but for the environment. To answer the question; In my experience, performance (sensu function operations) won't take a hit from overloaded workspace, however, large workspace will take a while to load when starting R. I turned off the feature to ask me about saving - I always dump workspace after closing R (see BondedDust's comment).